# Why is water bright in a T2 weighted image?

Tags: water, biophysics, half-life, nuclear-magnetic-resonance

I am new to study MRI. Please understand if some terminologies I use are wrong.

This might be a silly question, but I wonder why water is bright in a T2 weighted image. T2 relaxation is also called spin-spin relaxation, because FID signal decays faster when there is spin-spin interference. Then water must be denser in terms of proton, and thus FID of water decays fast and water should be black in an T2 weighted image. But in reality, water is bright in a T2 weighted image. Why is that?

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing two distinct concepts: proton density and T2. The T2 relaxation time is not strongly related to proton density. You have tissues with very similar proton densities that have strongly dissimilar T2.

The key for T2 is not the proton density, but how strongly the hydrogen nuclei interact with each other. The strength of interaction is not merely determined by the proton density, but more by their molecular arrangement.

So, the interaction between water spins is weak, which means that the T2 is relatively long. Thus, by the time we acquire the signal in a T2 weighted image, there has been little decay and therefore the signal is bright.